# Neo4j Security Error 18 in internet Explorer

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

While running a query in neo4j using internet explorer i am getting a security error 18 DOM , whereas the same query works fine in chrome .

Query that i am running

```
create (n);

SecurityError
```

Screenshot :

[image: Security Error 18 DOM]

Comment: Do you have a longer message into the javascript console of your browser ? With which user are you connected ?

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: ie 11 (11.0.9600.18860)

Comment: @logisima i am able to connect , i am connecting using neo4j as username but when i query then it throws a security error 18 DOM whereas in chrome it works fine

Comment: @TsTeaTime, seems like local storage is disabled in IE in your case. Can you please confirm? The site requires the same to work. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx5gt.png)

Comment: @Aman, can you check if my previous comment helps?

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani , Enable DOM Storage is already enable , still the error remains the same .

Comment: @TarunLalwani Dom Storage is already enabled

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by connecting to `http://127.0.0.1:7474/browser` instead of `http://localhost:7474/browser`.
There's also a [Neo4j developer webpage](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-security-error-18-when-using-internet-explorer-and-neo4j-browser/) suggesting that it would help to add WebSocket permissions to IE setup, but I didn't find that was necessary or sufficient.